# I'm trying to add a marker using Google Maps Javascript API but it isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

This is my Javascript code to obtain the marker. The page is loading the map but the marker doesn't appear.

```
function initMap(){
      var options = {
        zoom:13,
        center:{lat:42.3601,lng:-71.0589}//Change these coordinates to change the center
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);
    }
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3601, -71.0589);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:location,
      map:this
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format all your code as code. Also, please add text explaining your doubt. What is not working? Do you get any error?

Comment: The map loads but I can't get the markers to work.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. create the `marker` inside your `initMap` function (which most likely is the callback function that runs once the API is loaded)
2. use a valid value for the `google.maps.Map` object.  (the `map` variable inside the `initMap` function would be best, `this` where you have it is probably the `window` object).

```
function initMap(){
  var options = {
    zoom:13,
    center:{lat:42.3601,lng:-71.0589}//Change these coordinates to change the center
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);
  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3601, -71.0589);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:location,
    map:map
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9t75zbLf/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var options = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 42.3601,
      lng: -71.0589
    } //Change these coordinates to change the center
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3601, -71.0589);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```